# how to convert java date string to date in vbscript with lacale

Tags: java, date, vbscript

I have to convert a java string to date in vbscript with given locale. below are some of date string

```
Dim dstr,dstr2
dstr= 30 Oct 2013 07:49:37 GMT
dstr2 =30-Oct-2013 13:20:22 India Standard Time
```

From these if I remove there locale then below syntax work

```
CDate(replace(dstr,"GMT"),"")
CDate(replace(dstr,"India Standard Time"),"")
```

But it does not give Locale. can any body tell me how can I fetch date with local given in the string.

Comment: What is a java String? Java has several possibilities to get a String representation of a date, so you have to specify which one you want to convert

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I got your question correctly or not but here goes:

```
Dim dstr, dstr2, intRegionalCode
intRegionalCode = GetLocale()
dstr = "30 Oct 2013 07:49:37 GMT"
dstr2 = "30-Oct-2013 13:20:22 India Standard Time"
SetLocale("en-gb")
MsgBox CDate(replace(dstr,"GMT",""))
MsgBox CDate(replace(dstr2,"India Standard Time",""))

SetLocale("en-us")
MsgBox CDate(replace(dstr,"GMT",""))
MsgBox CDate(replace(dstr2,"India Standard Time",""))
SetLocale(intRegionalCode)
```

I hope this helps.

For more information you can check [here](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/windows-scripting/working-with-dates-and-times-in-vbscript/).

- GetLocale [help](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_getlocale.asp)

Comment: Yes, `GetLocale` and `SetLocale` are the functions TS needs.

Comment: Is there not a way which will take lacale automatically from the string. As for these set and get locale I will have to define a function having all the locale string and then match with those which locale to use.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a script and not a programming language. It has its limitations.